# bot terminated by other getUpdates request make sure that only one bot instance is running

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, binance, py-telegram-bot-api

Hello everyone In this module(telegram_interface.py) I have (send_msg) method which I need to call it in another modules, but whenever I try to import this module(telegram_interface) inside the other modules to call the send_msg method, I had the error that I'm calling getUpdates from more than one instance, is there away to avoid this to happen !

```
telegram_interface.py
```

```
import configparser
import telepot
import time
from database import Status
import datetime as dt
import place_orders as po
import requests

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config1.ini")

bot_token = str(config["TelegramBot1"]["bot_token"])
my_chat_id = str(config["TelegramBot1"]["my_chat_id"])
bot111 = telepot.Bot(bot_token)


def time_now():
    time = dt.datetime.now()
    time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S   //   %d-%m-%Y")
    return time


# def send_msg(text):
#     url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+bot_token + \
#         "/sendMessage?chat_id="+my_chat_id+"&parse_mode=Markdown&text="
#     http_request = url + text
#     response = requests.get(http_request)
#     return response.json()


def handle(msg):
    user_name = msg["from"]["first_name"] + " " + msg["from"]["last_name"]
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)

    if content_type == "text":
        command = msg["text"]
        if "/START" == command.upper():
            bot111.sendMessage(chat_id,
                               "Welcome "+user_name+" in your Auto Trading Bot! \n command [/help] to get more information about the bot. ")
        elif "/HELP" == command.upper():
            bot111.sendMessage(chat_id,
                               "Available commands are: \n **[ON, OFF] - Control the bot. \n **[balance] - Get your free USDT balance.")
        elif "ON" == command.upper():
            Status.save_status(collection="Status",
                               status=command.upper(), time=time_now())
            bot111.sendMessage(chat_id, "System is *Activated*.",
                               parse_mode="Markdown")
            with open("log.txt", "a") as log_file:
                log_file.write(
                    "System is Activated at : " + time_now() + "\n")
        elif "OFF" == command.upper():
            Status.save_status(collection="Status",
                               status=command.upper(), time=time_now())
            bot111.sendMessage(chat_id, "System is *Deactivated*.",
                               parse_mode="Markdown")
            with open("log.txt", "a") as log_file:
                log_file.write("System is Deactivated at : " +
                               time_now() + "\n")
        elif "BALANCE" == command.upper():
            free_balance = po.get_usdt_balance()
            bot111.sendMessage(chat_id,
                               "Your free balance is : *"+str(free_balance)+" USDT*", parse_mode="Markdown")
        else:
            bot111.sendMessage(chat_id,
                               "Unknown command, use [/help] to get more information.")


bot111.message_loop(handle)


while True:
    time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import any module in Python, it is being executed, for example let's imagine we have the following module `print_hello.py`:

```
print('hello world')
```

If you run it, it will print `hello world`. If you import this module:

```
import print_hello
```

it will print `hello world` too! So, if you import it multiple times, it will print `hello world` exactly that much times.
To avoid this, you need to simulate main entrypoint, edit `print_hello.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('hello world')
```

In this case, `hello world` will be printed only with running `print_hello.py`, but won't be printed if imported.
So, you should apply this to your lines of code:

```
bot111.message_loop(handle)


while True:
    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: it works perfect ....... thanks a lot :)